# Adding html5 server sent events in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember application and I want to add sse in it. The problem is that I cannot call the controllers function after receiving a message. i can call this by declaring a new instance of the controller like `var ac = new App.ActivecallsController; ac.addNewCall().` But it make a new instance that's why it does not change the value of activeCalls array in the controller.

```
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined"){
            self.set('source',new EventSource("http://localhost/sse/demo_sse.php"));
            var source=new EventSource("http://localhost/sse/demo_sse.php");
            source.onmessage=function(event){
                var data = $.parseJSON(event.data);
                console.log(data.length);
                if(data.length){
                   **//Here I want to call the addNewCall function.** 
                }
            }
        }
```

My controller is

```
App.ActivecallsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    activeCalls:[],
    content:[],
    addNewCall:function(model){
        var self= this;
        console.log('here');
        App.Cdrglobal.set('active_call',App.Cdrglobal.active_call+1);
        self.activeCalls.insertAt(0,model);
   }
});
```

Comment: With Ember Data you could do something like App.store.load(App.Message, message) but I see you are not using Ember Data here.

Comment: Why are you making two EventSource instances?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution

```
 APP.__container__.lookup('controller:activecalls').addNewCall(model);
```